# Rails 3 - how to organize / split up bloated controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, organization

I've been working on a CMS app to sharpen up my skills and the controllers are getting quite bloated with the definitions. I know it's possible to store stuff in lib/whatever.rb and then use require and include, but that doesn't quite work with controllers - at least, in my case, where I have before_filters. 
Without the definitions right in the controller, before_filters refuse to work.

Do all the defs HAVE to go in the controller or is there a way to take them out? (They are specific to that controller so they can't go in application controller.

Comment: you could create a controller with factorized `before_filter` and make your controllers inherit from it.

Comment: Can you make your question more specific by giving some examples? In a lot of cases where I've seen this issue is raised, the logic didn't have to be in the controllers at all (but rather, in models or other classes).

Comment: It might be helpful for you to download this gem and read through the source code to better understand the Controller eco-system: http://rubydoc.info/gems/inherited_resources/1.2.2/frames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a lot of things with mixin modules that will add behavior to an existing controller, or you can try and come up with a class hierarchy that will allow the controllers to inherit the required methods from their parent class.

In most applications I sub-class `ApplicationController` at least once in order to enforce some standards in certain contexts. For instance, all controllers relating to a Project would inherit from `ProjectController::Base`:

```
class ProjectController::Base < ApplicationController
  before_filter :must_be_logged_in
  before_filter :load_project

protected
  def load_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id] || params[:id])

  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    render(:template => 'not_found')
  end

  def must_be_logged_in
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: So you have a file called "ProjectController" under controllers?

Comment: A directory called `project_controller` with `base.rb` and several derived classes in it, each of which pertains to a particular type of resource, typically. `ProjectController` actually inherits from `ProjectController::Base` and has a few `skip_before_filter` settings to avoid trying to load projects on `index`, `new` or `create`, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

The [augmentation-plugin](https://github.com/henrik/augmentations) (it's rather a snippet) could be a solution for you.

#### What it does (add some methods to Object/Module)

```
class ::Object
  def self.augment(*mods)
    include *mods
    mods.each {|mod| class_eval &mod.augmentation }
  end
end

class ::Module
  def augmentation(&block)
    @augmentation ||= block
  end
end
```

#### What it allows you to do

```
# app/controllers/your_controller.rb
class YourController
  augment YourController::Stuff

  ...
end

# app/controllers/your_controller/stuff.rb
module YourController::Stuff
  augmentation do
    before_filter :something

    def something
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

You need to make sure that subfolders of folders in `/app` are included in Rails' autoload paths.

Comment: Rails 3 bakes this pattern right in with `ActiveSupport::Concern` and `included do ... end`.

Comment: Darn, I forgot that - working too much on legacy Rails 2.3 apps.